# $lastExitCode not working for 7-Zip update

Tags: powershell, 7zip

What I'm trying to do is back up some databases and part of the process is to zip them up so they're not only in one file, but a smaller file so I have the following code.

```
# 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, etc

$blocation = 'c:\SQLBackups'
$7zlocation = 'c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'
$date = Get-Date
$daynum = [int]$date.DayOfWeek

$month = Get-Date -Format MM
$day = (Get-Date).AddDays(0).ToString('dd')
$sqlfile = "*_backup_" + $date.Year + "_" + $month + "_" + $day + "_*.bak"

cd $blocation
& $7zlocation d ABOCH2_SQL_backup.zip *.bak
& $7zlocation u ABOCH2_SQL_backup.zip *.bak
if($lastExitCode -eq 0) {
  del /q *.bak
}
```

After emptying out the .zip file from previous runs, update the .zip file with the newly dumped databases and then only delete the databases after the .zip was successfully updated. Issue I'm facing is that after running this the .zip file is updated with the new databases. However, the `$lastExitCode` is not working so the databases that were successfully added to the .zip never get deleted and I end up with a backlog of old databases accumulating.

Am I missing something, or is something wrong?

Comment: Please expand on your claim that "$lastExitCode is not working" - how did you come to this conclusion? What is its value after the last invocation of 7-zip?

Comment: Also show the output of at least the update operation. Also, why are you deleting and adding files from/to the zip archive instead of renaming the old archive and creating a new one?

Comment: Also `del /q *.bak` should fail since `del` is an alias for `remove-item` and it uses different syntax. `del.exe /q *.bak` should address that. Consider using the cmdlet though instead.

Comment: @Matt `del` is a built-in command in `cmd.exe`, as it was with most (all?) versions of `command.com`.  There is no `del.exe` or `del.com`.  You'd have to run `cmd.exe /c "del /q *.bak"`.

Comment: @BaconBits Ah yes. that is true. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess that your delete operation is actually what is failing. I would question how this is being called or that maybe you are suppressing the error. The line that has `del /q *.bak` when executed should have an error along the lines of:

```
Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*.bak'.
At line:1 char:1
+ del /q *.bak
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveIt 
   emCommand
```

If you run the command `Get-Alias del` you would see that "del" is an alias for the `Remove-Item` cmdlet. Perhaps your `$lastexitcode` logic is sound? I would opt into the PowerShell way to remove those files:

```
Remove-Item *.csv -Confirm:$false
```

Or if you wanted you could use cmd

```
cmd.exe /c "del /q *.bak"
```

Comment: thanks everyone for your feedback! I'm going to chalk it up to the mind not thinking properly for the first day back at the office... I was pretty sure the "del /q *.bak" was working, but perhaps I may have just assumed it would work and only tested the code prior to that and left it without testing the deleting portion. Using the Remove-Item and testing with it produced exactly what I was looking for! the replies in this post have also allowed make note of better troubleshooting steps for the future